# Add elements to an already evaluated loop

Tags: javascript, node.js, loops

Good afternoon, I encounter the following problem, I am trying to loop through a list with subdirectories to add to an array (repositories) the routes of these subdirectories, this is my code:

```
        for (n=0; n<=pendingRepos.length; n++){

        subruta = pendingRepos[pendingRepos.length -1]
           pendingRepos.pop()                   
            c.list(subruta, function(err, sublist) {
            if (sublist.length != 0){         
                for (g=0; g < sublist.length; g++){

                if (sublist[g].type === 'd' ){
                    repositories.push(subruta+'/'+sublist[g].name)
                    pendingRepos.push(subruta+'/'+sublist[g].name)
                    }      

                else {files.push(subruta+'/'+sublist[g].name)}                       
                }

            }

            });   

        }
```

For example when starting the loop for my array pendingRepos has the following structure:

```
pendingRepos = ['/ dir1 / dir2', / dir3 / dir4 ']
```

the loop is executed correctly 2 times and the last element was removed, but at the time of the other loop to add another 'last' element to the array the first for loop does not take it into account.
I understand that the condition was already evaluated before I added more elements, is this correct? How can I avoid it?

Comment: You are  walking through pendingRepos in a weird way while also modifying it inside the loop with both `.pop()` and `.push()`.  This does not appear to be a reliable way of iterating that array.

Comment: Also `c.list()` appears to be non-blocking and asynchronous so you're trying to run a bunch of `c.list()` operations in parallel and all will finish after the master `for` loop.  This is entirely unpredictable.  I prepared an answer that addresses both of these, but then decided I don't really know what you're attempting to do with top level loop iteration while iterating something you are modifying inside the loop. That just made no sense to me at all.

Comment: What library is `c` in `c.list()`? Could you give the `npm` link for it?

Comment: @TheHansinator https://www.npmjs.com/package/ftp im using this module

Comment: @FrancoGaluzzi It's asynchronous, then (since it's contacting an FTP server). I will finish my answer for JavaScript that takes this into account, though I will add as an aside that if you are simply writing a shell script instead of part of a program (which seems to be likely, as you are setting global variables all over the place), I would highly recommend using something like Powershell instead, since unlike JavaScript, it will let you write commands that wait for the server to do its thing and respond back to you.

Comment: @TheHansinator 
I understand, that means that through the method I am using I will not be able to get what I am looking for?

Comment: @FrancoGaluzzi You can still do it, but you need to write your function completely differently (i.e. instead of using a `while` loop, you use a bunch more asynchronous functions).

Comment: @TheHansinator Actually it is part of a program, with the subdirectories that I add to the array my intention was to trigger other tasks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're treating the array of pending repos in two contradictory ways. The outer for loop:

```
for (n = 0; n <= pendingRepos.length; n++) { ... }
```

is treating `pendingRepos` as an immutable list, going through from beginning to end and processing each element. (And not doing this correctly, either - we should be iterating to `n < pendingRepos.length` if this is the option we're using).

The logic immediately after the loop, however,

```
subruta = pendingRepos[pendingRepos.length -1]
pendingRepos.pop()
```

treats `pendingRepos` as a mutable stack, from which you would keep processing the last element until the stack was empty.

In order to correctly process the array, you need to choose one or the other. Since it seems that the rest of your code is correctly using the stack approach, the loop at the top should be changed to match, which in this case would simply be

```
while (pendingRepos.length > 0) { ... }
```

The end result will look as follows:

```
while (pendingRepos.length > 0){
    const subruta = pendingRepos[pendingRepos.length -1]
    pendingRepos.pop()                   
    c.list(subruta, function(err, sublist) {
        if (sublist.length != 0){         
            for (let g = 0; g < sublist.length; g++){
                if (sublist[g].type === 'd' ){
                    repositories.push(subruta+'/'+sublist[g].name)
                    pendingRepos.push(subruta+'/'+sublist[g].name)
                } else {
                    files.push(subruta+'/'+sublist[g].name)
                }
            }
        }
    });
}
```

---

**EDIT:** The above answer only works if `c.list()` is a synchronous function that immediately runs your callback before returning - however, since it is contacting an FTP server, it is not. This means that the entire `while` loop will finish before any of those callbacks run, and anything they add to `pendingRepos` will not be processed. In order to use asynchronous functions, you have to structure your function completely differently, basically using more and more asynchronous functions as far up as you can go.

Fortunately, doing that is pretty easy in this case. What you are doing with `pendingRepos` is conceptually known as [depth-first search (or "DFS")](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth-first_search), where you search through a tree structure by repeating the search at each subnode. Using the stack of pending directories is one way to do DFS, and another way to do it is to use a recursive function (basically repeating the search function each time you reach a directory).

Here's a possible implementation of that, with the use of callbacks extending all the way out.

```
// an outer function for the whole operation. You would provide
// a callback that takes the lists of repositories and files.
function getTheRepos(startList, callbackForWholeThing) {
    // build up our lists of repositories and files
    const repositories = [];
    const files = [];

    // keep track of how many calculations are running
    let repoGetCount = 0;

    // an inner function to run exactly one result
    function getOneRepo(subruta) {
        // at the start, say we're running
        repoGetCount++;
        c.list(subruta, function(err, sublist) {
            if (sublist.length != 0){         
                for (let g = 0; g < sublist.length; g++){

                if (sublist[g].type === 'd' ){
                    repositories.push(subruta+'/'+sublist[g].name)
                    // for each directory we find, call this inner function again.
                    // This is the critical part that makes this all work.
                    getOneRepo(subruta+'/'+sublist[g].name)
                } else {
                    files.push(subruta+'/'+sublist[g].name)
                }
            }
            // at the end, say we're not running,
            // and call the whole callback if we're the last one
            repoGetCount--;
            if (repoGetCount === 0) {
                callbackForWholeThing(repositories, files);
            }
        }
    });

    // now that we have the function, run it on each of our
    // start directories to start things off
    for (let n = 0; n < startList.length; n++) {
        getOneRepo(startList[n]);
    }

    // the cogs are in motion, so now return.
    // The callback will be called when the tree has been searched.
}
```

Comment: It seems like there's a further problem that `c.list()` is probably asynchronous which loses all control over the loop conditions or loop order.

Comment: Thank you very much for the information, but I still get the same results, at the end of the while loop the array 'pendingRepos' contains the element that was added but the loop was not repeated

Comment: @FrancoGaluzzi Then it's probably as jfriend00 suggested - `c.list()` is an asynchronous function, and the entire `while` loop will run its course before any of the callbacks go off. This means that you need to structure your loop/function in a completely different way that takes that in mind, using recursive functions instead. I'll edit the question to show this.

Comment: Thank you very much, I am stuck in this part of my project, the c.list function of the ftp module https://www.npmjs.com/package/ftp returns me as a result a list with the directories of a remote location my intention is to list all subdirectories within that directory but I can't find a solution to this issue

Comment: Thanks i will try fix my issue with this answer, very nice explained